# casperjs test mode vs automation mode

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am new to casperjs, so forgive my ignorance, but I am very puzzled by why my test script is behaving differently than my automation code in this case.

I have a test script that contains:

```
casper.test.begin('Are we online?', 7, function suite(test) {
    casper.start("http://www.google.com/", function() {
        test.assertTitle("Google", "Connected to google, internet connection probably ok");
    });

casper.thenOpen("https://example.com/", function() {

    this.fill('form#logonForm', {
        'Name':    'user',
        'Password':    'pass',
    }, true);
});

casper.thenOpen("https://example.com/page2", function() {
  this.capture('screenshot.png'); //I am  logged in fine
});
```

But if I do it this way, I get logged out for some reason it does not work:

```
casper.start("https://example.com/LoginPage", function() {
   this.fill('form#logonForm', {
        'Name':    'user',
        'Password':    'pass',
    }, true);
});

casper.thenOpen("https://example.com/page2", function() {
  this.capture('screenshot.png'); //this shows me I am NOT logged in, any idea why? 
});
```

This is not my exact code I have distilled/simplified, hopefully I did not leave out any important distinction, but as far as I can tell seems to be due to writing it in a test suite vs not?

Comment: thanks, I made edit to include more, thank you for your help, how does this look?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference how CasperJS/PhantomJS behaves if the scripts are the same. The login urls look different. One has a path `/LoginPage` the supposedly same URL in the first snippet does not.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful to know I am barking up the wrong tree.